Which statistical test for testing difference between two groups of normalized data/proportions?
I have two groups of data (treatment vs control) with 3 samples/replicates in each group. For each sample, I have n observations and for each observation I have quantified whether they are of type A or type B (where the sum of type A and type B observations equals n). Because the total number of observations differs between samples, I have then normalized the number of type A and type B observations to the total number of observations (ie calculated the percentage/relative proportion of TypeA and TypeB observations in each sample).
Here is some example data:

I want to test whether the relative proportion of type B observations is significantly different between the two groups, but I'm unsure how. Had I not had to "normalize" the data by n, I would have used a simple t-test on the number of TypeB observations. Had I only had one replicate/sample in each group, I would have used a Chi square test for a difference in proportions. Any suggestions on which statistical test to use in this case?
